# Mobile site renders CSS pixels at physical pixel resolution?

Tags: css, web, mobile-website, pixel

I'm having a difficult time understanding the problem, let alone explaining it, so I have a picture of the issue.

[image: Screenshot of the mobile page]

I'm using ratios of 100% and 100vw for element widths. Everything renders at the right scale, and when I inspect the element it says that it is the correct width, but it seems to be rendering at the actual physical pixel size of the device. I could be completely wrong about that, I'm not entirely sure. I've never encountered this particular issue before.

As you could likely guess, I need the body of the page to fill the mobile device's viewport width. Any help is great. Thanks.

Comment: have you got a external link to have a look?

Comment: quirksmode.org: [A pixel is not a pixel is not a pixel](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html)

Comment: I read that a few minutes ago. I have the meta tag already.

Comment: It's also possible that one element is way too wide and forcing everything else to squeeze up. No way of telling without a link or demo, though.

Comment: jasperandrew.com/work/pipedream

Comment: <footer> -> <nav class="row"> has a width of 1100px. That's the issue.

Comment: @Danny H Haha, I found it at almost exactly the same time you did. The footer's overflow is hidden, so I couldn't see it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to the following:

```
<footer>
  <nav class="row">...</nav> <!-- This has a width of 1100px -->
</footer>
```

Remove the fixed with on the nav.row and it should work.

Comment: I'd like to give you the credit for the answer, but your solution is in the comments. If you change your answer to show the problem you found, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting everyone's time, it was just a rogue element that was too wide, but the overflow was hidden so I couldn't see it. I guess that's what happens when your stylesheet gets too long.

Thanks for your help.